# What subject does this fall under (differential curves maybe?)

Tags: calculus

I found a question where I don't even know where it comes from (except, vaguely, a Calc 2 class--but in my past Calc 2 class I never saw anything like this):

> Find the angle of rotation needed to eliminate $xy$ from the equation $2x^2 +2\sqrt{3}xy+4y^2 +8x +8\sqrt{3}y=50$.

Can anyone tell me the basic method of doing this, or at least what topic this kind of problem falls under?  Is this some kind of change of coordinates?  Does that mean that you need to find two new parameters in an orthonormal basis such that the equation becomes ... linear?  Or just a polynomial?

Comment: It's a problem in the theory of quadratic forms, the diagonalization of symmetric matrices, and rotation theory. You'd usually see it in a course on linear algebra. But plenty of good high schools teach it in precalculus.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: this function is not a quadratic form, of course. But the process for solving this question remains similar!

Comment: And your goal is to express the formula in new coordinates $(x',y')$ with no cross terms $x'y'$. That amounts to diagonalizing the matrix by an orthonormal basis (a rotation) and using the eigenvalues.

Comment: @FPE: after a suitable translation, it is...

Comment: @symplectomorphic: I agree, but strictly speaking the given function is not. We can't diagonalize a symmetric matrix here from start, as one would do with a quadratic form. As you say, one has to translate first. It is like you were saying that affine transformations and linear transformations are exactly the same object.

Comment: @FPE: I said no such thing. I said this is a problem in the theory of quadratic forms. That is true. It also involves a whole lot of other things: basic arithmetic, the idea of a function, making an appropriate affine translation... that doesn't mean it isn't about quadratic forms. It's wrong to infer from "this is about quadratic forms" that you don't need to know anything except what a quadratic form is.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: looking at my first comment, I didn't implied that you said it was the same, I was basically adding this comment as a complement to yours, to emphasize the fact that the OP would have to do a bit more work in this case. Anyway, I feel like we are on the same page, though I made a communication error.

Answer (score 0):

Say that $Q\colon \mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the function that maps $(x,y)$ to $2x^2 +2\sqrt{3}xy+4y^2 +8x +8\sqrt{3}y$. Note that the set of points $(x,y)$ so that $Q(x,y)=50$ is an ellipse ([picture](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28x%2Cy%29%20where%202x%5E2%2B2sqrt%283%29xy%2B4y%5E2%2B8x%2B8sqrt%283%29y%3D50)).

Let $e_1$ be $(1,0)$ and $e_2$ be $(0,1)$, the vectors of the standard basis for $\mathbb R^2$.
Then we have:
$\begin{align*}
Q(xe_1 + ye_2) = 2x^2 +2\sqrt{3}xy+4y^2 +8x +8\sqrt{3}y &= 2\left[x^2 + \sqrt{3}xy + 2y^2\right]+8x+8\sqrt 3y\\
 &= 2(x+\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}y)^2 + \dfrac{5}{2}y^2 + 8x + 8\sqrt{3}y.
\end{align*}$

Now we want to find a new basis $e_1', e_2'$ so that the expression of $Q$ in this basis
does not contain $xy$. Here, it suffices to change $x+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}y$ to $x'$:
let $e_1' = e_1$ and $e_2' = -\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}e_1 + \frac{1}{2}e_2$.
Now, we have $Q(xe_1' + ye_2') = Q((x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y)e_1 + ye_2) = 2x^2 + \dfrac{5}{2}y^2 + 8x + 4\sqrt 3y$.

Basically, we tilted the $y$-axis so that it is parallel with one of the axis of the ellipse. Now, it simply remains to compute the angle between $e_2'$ and $e_2$, which you can do with a simple dot product ($e_2$ and $e_2'$ have norm $1$).